# ros-fuerte-pr2-desktop

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

following the guide, `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-desktop` gives the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-fuerte-pr2-desktop
```

Anyone know why it's not found?

Ubuntu 11.10, 64 bit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32893/ros-fuerte-pr2-desktop/) by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-04-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-28**:
What OS are you on?

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-04-28**:
Ubuntu 11.10

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-28**:
Did you run 'sudo apt-get update' before trying to install ros-fuerte-pr2-desktop?

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-04-28**:
yeah, I installed ros-fuerte-desktop-full to get going... when I check my software list (in synaptic package manager), I see other pr2 related packages, but not desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a few packages in the pr2-desktop variant which fail to build on oneiric.  For now you will have to install the individual packages.  The pr2 variants are listed in [REP 108](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html#robot-specific)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2